# Question on three conjectured closed-form representations related to the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, closed-form, riemann-zeta

**Question**: Can the following three conjectured closed form representations be proven to be correct assuming $\Re(s)>1$ and $m\in \mathbb{P}$?

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a(n) \frac{n\, m^{n\, s}}{\left(m^{n\, s}-1\right)^2}\right)=\frac{1}{1-m^s}\tag{1}$$

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a(n)}{m^{n s}-1}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-m^{-s}}\right)\tag{2}$$

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\phi(n)}{m^{n s}-1}\right)=\frac{1}{m^s+m^{-s}-2}\tag{3}$$

---

The arithmetic function $a(n)$ referenced on the left sides of formulas (1) and (2) above is defined as

$$a(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{d|n} \mu(d)\, d\tag{4}$$

and $\phi(n)$ referenced on the left side of formula (3) above is Euler's totient function.

---

Note that $a(n)\, n=\sum\limits_{d|n} \mu(d)\, d$ corresponds to [OEIS entry A023900 Dirichlet inverse of Euler totient function (A000010)](https://oeis.org/A023900) and

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N A023900(n)\, n^{-s}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s-1)},\quad\Re(s)\ge 2\tag{5}$$

whereas

$$\underset{\text{N}\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \phi(n)\, n^{-s}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)},\quad\Re(s)>2\tag{6}$$

---

I suspect the closed-form representations in formulas (1) to (3) above may actually be more generally valid for $\Re(s)>0$ and integer $m>1$ or perhaps even $m>1$, but my primary interest is the more limited case stated in the question above for reasons that will become apparent in the formulas below.

---

The left and right sides of formula (1) above are related to the following two formulas for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$

$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\underset{M,N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\sum\limits_{m=2}^M 1_{m\in\mathbb{P}}\, \log(m) \sum\limits_{n=1}^N a(n) \frac{n\, m^{n\, s}}{\left(m^{n\, s}-1\right)^2}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{7}$$

$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\underset{M\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{m=2}^M 1_{m\in\mathbb{P}}\, \frac{\log(m)}{1-m^s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{8}$$

where $1_{m\in\mathbb{P}}$ is the prime indicator function which returns the value $1$ if $m$ is a prime and zero otherwise.

---

The left and right sides of formula (2) above are related to the following two formulas for $\log\zeta(s)$:

$$\log\zeta(s)=\underset{M,N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{m=2}^M 1_{m\in\mathbb{P}} \sum _{n=1}^N \frac{a(n)}{m^{n s}-1}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{9}$$

$$\log\zeta(s)=\underset{M\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{m=2}^M 1_{m\in\mathbb{P}}\, \log\left(\frac{1}{1-m^{-s}}\right)\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{10}$$

---

The left and right sides of formula (3) above are related to the following two formulas for $K_\Omega(s)$

$$K_\Omega(s)=\underset{M,N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{m=2}^M 1_{m\in\mathbb{P}}\, \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\phi(n)}{m^{n s}-1}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{11}$$

$$K_\Omega(s)=\underset{M\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{m=2}^M \frac{1_{m\in\mathbb{P}}}{m^s+m^{-s}-2}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{12}$$

which represent alternate ways to evaluate the Dirichlet series

$$K_\Omega(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N 1_{n=p^k}\, \Omega(n)\, n^{-s}\right),\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{13}$$

where $1_{n=p^k}$ is the prime-power indicator function which returns the value $1$ if $n$ is a prime-power and zero otherwise and $\Omega(n)$ counts the number of non-distinct primes in $n$ (i.e. $\Omega(n)=k$ when $n=p^k$).

---

I believe formula (13) for $K_\Omega(s)$ above can be analytically continued from $\Re(s)>1$ to $\Re(s)>0$ as follows

$$K_\Omega(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b(n) \log(\zeta(n s))\right),\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{14}$$

where

$$b(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{d|n} d^2 \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{15}$$

---

Note that $b(n)\, n=\sum\limits_{d|n} d^2 \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$ corresponds to [OEIS Entry A007434](https://oeis.org/A007434) for the Jordan function $J_2(n)$ which is a generalization of Euler's totient function $\phi(n)$ and

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \left(\sum\limits_{d|n} d^2 \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\right) n^{-s}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(s)},\quad\Re(s)>3\tag{16}$$

---

I believe formulas (7) to (12) above for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$, $\log\zeta(s)$, and $K_\Omega(s)$ are all valid for $\Re(s)>1$, but note formula (12) above for $K_\Omega(s)$ converges for $\Re(s)<-1$ as well as $\Re(s)>1$ and evaluates to $K_\Omega(-s)$=$K_\Omega(s)$ for $|\Re(s)|>1$.

Comment: Please define your notation $m\in \mathbb{P}$ at the beginning of your question.

Comment: @Somos $m\in \mathbb{P}$ is just a way of saying $m$ is an element of the prime numbers. My question was specific to $\Re(s)>1$ and $m\in\mathbb{P}$ because of the relationship of formulas (1) to (3) with formulas (7) to (12). I indicated in my question I suspect formulas (1) to (3) may be more generally valid for any $\Re(s)>0$ and perhaps $m>1$, but I now suspect they may be even more generally valid for $\Re(s)>0$ and $\Re(m)>1$. But this all based on a few evaluations of formulas (1) to (3), and I'm hoping someone can derive a proof of formulas (1) to (3).

Comment: In your equations $(1),(2),(3)$ your could replace $m^s$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Somos Perhaps that would be more general, but would it provide new insight perhaps leading to a proof?

Comment: @Somos After replacing $m^s$ with $z$ in formulas (1) to (3), limited investigation seems to suggest the resulting formulas are all three valid for $|\Re(z)>1|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity and generality make the definition $\,z := m^{-s}.\,$ Then your
three equations become
$$ -\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) \frac{n\,z^{-n}}{(z^{-n}-1)^2} =\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}},\tag{1}$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{z^{-n}-1} = \log\Big(\frac{1}{1-z}\Big), \tag{2}$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{z^{-n}-1} = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}. \tag{3}$$
They all have radius of convergence $1$. For some background on series
such as these refer to Wikipedia article
[Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series).

Comment: 3 clearly follows by expansion of LHS and grouping (allowed by absolute convergence on $|z|\le r<1$) as the generic term $z^m$ has coefficient $\sum_{d|m} \phi(d)=m$ which is the coefficient of RHS as that is the Koebe function; would expect 2 to follow the same way and then 1 follows from 2 by differentiation